# AWS LoadBalancer Target group return unhealthy status for registered target

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-elb

i created AWS EKS cluster with eksctl with one node group
eksctl created default one nodegroup and vpc and security groups

i applyed deployment, service and alb ingress

But when i apply Load balancer target group return unheathy status for the registered target

here are my manifest files:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: techcare-apigw
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: techcare-apigw
  annotations:
    linkerd.io/inject: enabled
  namespace: techcare
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: techcare-apigw
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: techcare-apigw
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: 435109652403.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/api-gateway:1.0.67
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: techcare-apigw
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          env:
            - name: PORT
              value: "3000"
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "500Mi"  # Set the requested memory
              cpu: "0.4"      # Set the requested CPU
            limits:
              memory: "500Mi"  # Set the requested memory
              cpu: "0.4"       # Set the CPU limi

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: techcare-apigw-s
  namespace: techcare # Specify the correct namespace here
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: techcare-apigw
    app: techcare-apigw-s
spec:
  selector:
    app: techcare-apigw
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
  type: NodePort

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: techcare-apigw
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: instance
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}]'

spec:
  ingressClassName: alb # Corrected Ingress class name
  defaultBackend: # Define default backend here
    service:
      name: techcare-apigw-s  # Replace with the name of your default backend service
      port:
        number: 80  # Replace with the port number of your default backend service
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: techcare-apigw-s
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Pod: 192.168.0.14 Port: 3000/TCP

```
kubectl describe po  techcare-apigw-8577565548-68x5w -n techcare                                                                                                                               ✔  16.0.0 Node  nbozic@techcare.eu-central-1.eksctl.io ○  10:07:05  
Name:         techcare-apigw-8577565548-68x5w
Namespace:    techcare
Priority:     0
Node:         ip-192-168-2-244.eu-central-1.compute.internal/192.168.2.244
Start Time:   Sun, 10 Dec 2023 21:13:09 +0100
Labels:       app=techcare-apigw
              pod-template-hash=8577565548
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           192.168.0.14
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.0.14
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/techcare-apigw-8577565548
Containers:
  techcare-apigw:
    Container ID:   containerd://1a27857b06fa9b04825df077c34a884ea0d326691e731dfd886ad9f584c0eee5
    Image:          435109652403.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/api-gateway:1.0.67
    Image ID:       435109652403.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/api-gateway@sha256:1704e67539b189e374422e7d0e0ac689cfcfb38e07544651f76e4e8e3318ec01
    Port:           3000/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Sun, 10 Dec 2023 21:13:10 +0100
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     400m
      memory:  500Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:     400m
      memory:  500Mi
    Environment:
      PORT:  3000
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-rfs7j (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-rfs7j:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Guaranteed
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  54m   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned techcare/techcare-apigw-8577565548-68x5w to ip-192-168-2-244.eu-central-1.compute.internal
  Normal  Pulling    54m   kubelet            Pulling image "435109652403.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/api-gateway:1.0.67"
  Normal  Pulled     54m   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "435109652403.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/api-gateway:1.0.67" in 125.477604ms (125.48953ms including waiting)
  Normal  Created    54m   kubelet            Created container techcare-apigw
  Normal  Started    54m   kubelet            Started container techcare-apigw
```

Service: 192.168.0.14:3000,192.168.0.174:3000

```
Name:                     techcare-apigw-s
Namespace:                techcare
Labels:                   app=techcare-apigw-s
                          app.kubernetes.io/name=techcare-apigw
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=techcare-apigw
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.100.105.47
IPs:                      10.100.105.47
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               3000/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30633/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.0.14:3000,192.168.0.174:3000
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Ingres:

```
ubectl describe  ing techcare-apigw -n techcare                                                                                                                                               ✔  16.0.0 Node  nbozic@techcare.eu-central-1.eksctl.io ○  10:06:45  
Name:             techcare-apigw
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        techcare
Address:          k8s-techcare-techcare-398c60dce3-1088437205.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Default backend:  techcare-apigw-s:80 (192.168.0.14:3000,192.168.0.174:3000)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *           
              /   techcare-apigw-s:80 (192.168.0.14:3000,192.168.0.174:3000)
Annotations:  alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: [{"HTTP": 80}]
              alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
              alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: instance
Events:
  Type    Reason                  Age   From     Message
  ----    ------                  ----  ----     -------
  Normal  SuccessfullyReconciled  6s    ingress  Successfully reconciled
```

REgistered targets:

```
i-072d62e9909ede6a2 techcare-ng-techcare-Node   30633   eu-central-1b   Unhealthy   Health checks failed    Normal
```

Inbound rules for registered target

```
–   sgr-0f7b3f52d3d1ad2d4   1025 - 65535    TCP sg-063ebb47ba0744fa6    eksctl-techcare-nodegroup-ng-techcare-SG-1RB6XD3XXG2X5  [IngressInterCluster] Allow worker nodes in group ng-techcare to communicate with control plane (kubelet and workload TCP ports)        –
–   sgr-075fd5dd26a59fccc   443 TCP sg-063ebb47ba0744fa6    eksctl-techcare-nodegroup-ng-techcare-SG-1RB6XD3XXG2X5  [IngressInterClusterAPI] Allow worker nodes in group ng-techcare to communicate with control plane (workloads using HTTPS port, commonly used with extension API servers)       –
–   sgr-036726207e0da1569   30633   TCP sg-0e505d2b23eb798d9    eksctl-techcare-nodegroup-ng-techcare-SG-1RB6XD3XXG2X5  elbv2.k8s.aws/targetGroupBinding=shared     –
–   sgr-0bcee2058e33470cd   All All sg-007555ad1cfef2d69    eksctl-techcare-cluster-ClusterSharedNodeSecurityGroup-11P071CYQME40    Allow managed and unmanaged nodes to communicate with each other (all ports)    –   
–   sgr-0205fe6cd74477975   All All sg-00e19f6eb06e9427e    eksctl-techcare-cluster-ClusterSharedNodeSecurityGroup-11P071CYQME40    Allow nodes to communicate with each other (all ports)  –
```

[image]
**kubectl port-forward techcare-apigw-8577565548-68x5w -n techcare 2000:3000 return 200**